# How to view the SQL generated by an Opaleye query?

Tags: haskell, opaleye

In the [Opaleye Tutorial](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/blob/master/Doc/Tutorial/TutorialBasic.lhs), line 88 lists the following example `ghci` command.

```
ghci> printSql personQuery
```

`personQuery` there is a predefined query, and it appears that `printSql` is a function which prints the SQL generated by it.

Where is this `printSql` function defined? I have searched through all the modules of the [opaleye package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye) and do not see it defined there.

**How can I see the SQL generated by an opaleye query?**

Comment: `printSql` [is defined in the tutorial itself](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/blob/master/Doc/Tutorial/TutorialBasic.lhs#L854), in terms of [`showSqlForPostgres`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.6.0.0/docs/Opaleye-Sql.html#v:showSqlForPostgres). Note that the tutorial uses explicit or qualified imports for everything; that being so, if the function came from Opaleye you'd be able to discover that at once through the import list.

Comment: @duplode that answers my question, thank you.